# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a ecommerce site using the `commerce.js` library. I have already 8 products in the library API. I have a `Products.js` component where I'm passing those array of product objects I got from `App.js` and again passing single product object to the `Product.js` component. To do this, I'm using mapping function to pass each object as props to the `Product.js` component. And I'm receiving this error. I tried commenting out the mapping block and only console logged the `products` variable from `App.js` and the prop `products` in `Products.js`, there I'm getting all the 8 products so no problem in there. But I don't get it why I'm getting this error in the mapping function.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { commerce } from "./lib/commerce";
import { Products, Navbar } from "./components";

function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const fetchProduct = async () => {
    const data = await commerce.products.list();
    setProducts(data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProduct();
  }, []);

  console.log("products", products);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Products products={products} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Products.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import Product from "./Product/Product";
import useStyles from "./style";

const Products = ({ products }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Grid container justifyContent="center" spacing={4}>
        {products.data.map((product) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

**Product.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardMedia,
  CardContent,
  CardActions,
  Typography,
  IconButton,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { AddShoppingCart } from "@material-ui/icons";
import useStyles from "./styles";

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={product.media.source}
        title={product.name}
      />
      <CardContent>
        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
          <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
            {product.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5">
            {product.price.formatted_with_symbol}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography
          variant="body2"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.description }}
        />
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
        <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
          <AddShoppingCart />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Comment: `const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);` products starts off as an array, and arrays don't have a `.data` property on them. Did you mean to do a different initial value? Or perhaps did you mean to do `products.map` instead of `products.data.map`?

Comment: No when I got the data from the API it had like this `products { data: [Array of my products], metadata: {...}` So to map I had to go through the chaining process

Comment: Ok, then change your initial state so it has the same shape. It needs to be an object with a data property that is an array. ie, `useState({ data: [] })`

Comment: could you please explain why I had to set like this, It is working this way but when I'm setting the API response in array eventually through chaining I'm accessing the data. But why I had to explicitly set the initial value to `{data:[]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your **App.js** change your `fetchProduct` function as follows:

```js
const fetchProduct = async = {
    const products = await commerce.products.list();
    setProducts(products.data);
}
```

and then in your **Products.js** map over the products instead of products.data,

```js
      {products.map((product) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Grid>
      ))}
```

**EXPLANATION:**
The initial State of products is an empty array, which is passed down to the products component, where you tried `products.data.map()` but products is an array (initially) and there is no data property on arrays, so it threw error.
There are several ways you can get around this, but **if** you are only using the products data from the response then you can go with the above approach, where you map over the `products` not `products.data` and `setProducts()` with the products array instead of products object.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I also applied the same method but here I used destructuring so `const {data} = await commerce.products.list()`

Answer (score 2):

Do you can to  attached screen with error?

I think, you try to read  data before is are  loading, you can prevent this by add something like this (products.data || []).map for example.. or change default state in App.js on useState({data:[]})

Comment: Thanks, I think that was the problem I was calling the mapping function before getting the api response. But In `App.js` I used `async await` and then saved the response in my variable. So a bit confused here.

Comment: useEffect with empty array in arguments, will work like componentDidMount , he will called after first render, when you else don't get the data

Comment: so can I just pass the data as argument in the useEffect so when I have the data it'll automatically re-render?

Comment: If you add data to the dependency array for usefetch, it will cause unnecessary rerenders and calls to `fetchProduct` function